# mapping domain name server ip list using any one of the name server ip

Tags: php, ip, reverse-engineering

I'm able to get the nameserver ip by using this code:

```
$result = exec("host -t NS google.com", $outputLines);
foreach ($outputLines as $outputLine)
{
    $buffer = explode(" ", $outputLine);
    $nsList[] = $buffer[3];
}
$ipList = array_map("gethostbyname", $nsList);
print_r($ipList);
```

Now `$ipList` holds the IP list. Is there any way to get all these IP by inputting any one of the IP in `$ipList`.

It is like reverse process, I want to get all the IP which `$ipList` variable holds by inputting any one of the IP present in the `$ipList` variable.

Comment: I am a bit confused as you managed to use the use the word "ip" 9 times with different purposes in the paragraph right after the code sample.. in other words.. do you want to find out all the other ip addresses for name servers that handle a certain domain (given that you already know one of them) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly what you are asking which is that you want to be able to find all of the IP addresses of the nameservers in a group of nameservers (ie, NS1, NS2, NS3...) given a single nameservers IP address?

This isnt... quite easily possible, however it IS possible to do although you would have to go a LONG way around the problem to do it. You would have to hook into external services to try and get the DNS name being used by the nameserver residing on an IP address, and then try and find a group of domains that are being used by the nameserver, and then analyze the nameservers being used by those domains (crossing your fingers that you get them all) and then essentially run your existing script against them.

Maybe im wrong but i think you may be approaching whatever problem you have the wrong way, i used to work in domain management and would run into these kinds of problems all the time and unfortunately it ends being alot of DNS data aggregation and analysis work in order to solve these kinds of problems easily.

Comment: yes shane, you're right. I too realised that i'm going in a wrong way. now i've only ip for sitenames in my db. these data will be renewed every month. so, i'm going to add nameservers too. now i can easily map given ip with name servers ip. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

So you want to be able to find all the values in an array that match a certain IP address. This can be done with [`array_keys()` (man page)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and its optional `search_value` parameter.

```
$ip_we_are_searching_for = '192.168.0.1';
$matching_keys = array_keys($ip, $ip_we_are_searching_for);
var_dump($matching_keys);
```